# Discriminant of the Kummer extension of p-adics

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, discriminant, kummer-theory

Let $u\in \mathbb{Z}_p^*$ be a unit in the ring of $p$-adic integers. Assume that $u^{1/p}\not\in \mathbb{Q}_p$, in other words $u$ is not a $p$-power.

Define by $K:=\mathbb{Q}_p(u^{1/p})$. What is the discriminant of $K$?

The discriminant of the defining polynomial $f(x):=x^p-u$ is $\Delta(f)=(-1)^{p(p-1)/2}p^pu^{p-1}$, and I know that $\Delta(K/\mathbb{Q}_p)|\Delta(f)$, however can one explicitly compute $\Delta(K/\mathbb{Q}_p)$?

I think the question reduces to how do I find an integral basis for $\mathcal{O}_K$, or how do I find a uniformizer for $\mathcal{O}_K$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to consider whether or not $u^{p-1} \equiv 1 \bmod p^2$. This "Wieferich prime" criterion comes up in the number field setting in order to determine whether $\mathbf Q(\sqrt[p]{a})$ has ring of integers $\mathbf Z[\sqrt[p]{a}]$ when $p$ is prime and $a$ is a squarefree integer other than $\pm 1$: see the last theorem [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/integersradical.pdf).  It is also relevant in the local case.

You tell us that $u$ is not a $p$th power in $\mathbf Q_p$. That implies $x^p - u$ is irreducible over $\mathbf Q_p$ (over *all* fields, even those of characteristic $p$, $x^p - a$ is irreducible when $a$ is not a $p$th power in the field).  Let $K = \mathbf Q_p(\sqrt[p]{u})$, so $[K:\mathbf Q_p] = p$.
Since "$n=ef$" in local fields, when $n = p$ either $e = p$ or $f = p$. So $K$ is either totally ramified or unramified.

**Theorem**. *If $u^{p-1} \not\equiv 1 \bmod p^2$ then $K/\mathbf Q_p$ is totally ramified with prime element $\sqrt[p]{u}-u$ and ring of integers $\mathbf Z_p[\sqrt[p]{u}]$.*

*Proof*. The polynomial $(x+u)^p - u$, with root $\sqrt[p]{u}-u$, is Eisenstein at $p$ since its constant term $u^p - u$ is divisible by $p$ but not by $p^2$ due to the hypothesis in the theorem. (The intermediate coefficients are all obviously divisible by $p$.)  Hence $K$, which is $\mathbf Q_p(\sqrt[p]{u}-u)$, is totally ramified with prime element $\sqrt[p]{u}-u$. In every totally ramified extension of $\mathbf Q_p$, the powers of an arbitrary prime in that extension is a power basis for its ring of integers, so the integers of $K$ equal $\mathbf Z_p[\sqrt[p]{u}-u]$, which is also $\mathbf Z_p[\sqrt[p]{u}]$.  QED

**Corollary**. *If $u^{p-1} \not\equiv 1 \bmod p^2$, then ${\rm disc}(K/\mathbf Z_p)$ equals ${\rm disc}(x^p - u)$ up to unit factors*.

*Proof*.  The discriminant equals ${\rm disc}(x^p - u)$ since the ring of integers has powers of $\sqrt[p]{u}$ as a basis.  QED

**Theorem**. *If $u^{p-1} \equiv 1 \bmod p^2$ then $K/\mathbf Q_p$ is unramified.*

*Proof*.
This can be seen by a direct calculation when $p = 2$: when $u \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ and $u$ is not a square, then $u \equiv 5 \equiv -3 \bmod 8$, so
$\mathbf Q_2(\sqrt{u}) = \mathbf Q_2(\sqrt{-3})$, which is unramified over $\mathbf Q_2$.

Now we can suppose $p > 2$. We'll prove the theorem by proving the contrapositive: if $K/\mathbf Q_p$ is ramified then $u^{p-1} \not\equiv 1 \bmod p^2$.

Let $\alpha = \sqrt[p]{u}-u$, so $\alpha \not\in \mathbf Q_p$ and thus $K = \mathbf Q_p(\alpha)$, as $[K:\mathbf Q_p] = p$, a prime. Thus the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbf Q_p$ has to be of degree $p$. Since $\alpha$ is obviously a root of
$$
(x+u)^p - u
$$
in $\mathbf Q_p[x]$, which has degree $p$, this is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbf Q_p$. Therefore ${\rm N}_{K/\mathbf Q_p}(\alpha) = \pm(u^p-u)$, which is $0 \bmod p$, so $|\alpha|_p = \sqrt[p]{|{\rm N}_{K/\mathbf Q_p}(\alpha)|_p} < 1$.

Suppose $K/\mathbf Q_p$ is ramified. Then, because $[K:\mathbf Q_p] = p$, the extension is totally ramified. Writing $\pi$ for a prime in $K$, $p$ and $\pi^p$ are unit multiples in $K$. Thus their norms down to $\mathbf Q_p$ are unit multiples in $\mathbf Q_p$, so $|{\rm N}_{K/\mathbf Q_p}(\pi)|_p = |p|_p$.

Let $r = {\rm ord}_{\pi}(\alpha)$, so $r \geq 1$ since $|\alpha|_p < 1$.
Write $\alpha = \pi^r v$ for some unit $v$ in $K$. Taking norms of both sides and recalling that ${\rm N}_{K/\mathbf Q_p}(\alpha) = \pm(u^p-u)$,
$$
|u^p - u|_p = |{\rm N}_{K/\mathbf Q_p}(\pi)|_p^r = |p|_p^r = |p^r|_p,
$$
so ${\rm ord}_p(u^p-u) = r$.  We are going to show $r = 1$, so the highest power of $p$ dividing $u^p - u$ is $p$. Thus the highest power of $p$ dividing $u^{p-1} - 1$ is also $p$, which implies $u^{p-1} \not\equiv 1 \bmod p^2$.

Since
$$
0 = (\alpha + u)^p - u = \alpha^p + \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} \binom{p}{i}\alpha^i u^{p-i} + (u^p-u),
$$
we have
$$
\alpha^p + \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} \binom{p}{i}\alpha^i u^{p-i} = -(u^p-u).
$$
We'll determine the $\pi$-adic valuation of both sides.

Since ${\rm ord}_{\pi}(\alpha) = r$ and ${\rm ord}_{\pi}(p) = p$, on the left side we have ${\rm ord}_{\pi}(\alpha^p) = pr$ and the $i$th term in the sum
has $\pi$-adic valuation $p + ri$.  Among the valuations
$pr, p + r, \ldots, p + (p-1)r$, the unique minimal value is $p+r$ since $p+r < pr$ due to $p$ being odd and $r \geq 2$. (We can have $p+r = pr$ only when $p=2$ and $r = 2$, and $pr < p+r$ when $r = 1$).  That makes the left side above have $\pi$-adic valuation $p+r$.

On the right side above, ${\rm ord}_p(u^p-u) = r$, so ${\rm ord}_{\pi}(u^p-u) = pr$.  Thus $p+r = pr$, which is impossible when $p > 2$ and $r \geq 2$.

This contradiction shows $r = 1$ when $p > 2$.  We already saw that having $r = 1$ makes $u^{p-1} \not\equiv 1 \bmod p^2$.  QED

**Corollary**. *If $u^{p-1} \equiv 1 \bmod p^2$, then ${\rm disc}(K/\mathbf Z_p)$ equals $1$ up to unit factors*.

*Proof*.  The discriminant is divisible by $p$ if and only if the extension is ramified, and $K/\mathbf Q_p$ is unramified in this case. QED

When $u^{p-1} \equiv 1 \bmod p^2$, the ring of integers of $K$ is bigger than $\mathbf Z_p[\sqrt[p]{u}]$ since the discriminant of $\mathbf Z_p[\sqrt[p]{u}]$ over $\mathbf Z_p$ is ${\rm disc}(x^p- u)$, which is divisible by $p$.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a great answer. I have two follow-up questions. 1. Did you use at any point $u$ is a unit? 2. Did you have to assume that $u$ is square-free at any point (as Cornad's reference suggests)?

Comment: I used that $u$ is a $p$-adic unit when I rewrote $u^p \not\equiv u \bmod p^2$ as $u^{p-1} \not\equiv 1 \bmod p^2$. If $u$ were not a unit then I could not have done that division while keeping the modulus as $p^2$.  There is no issue of being squarefree in this $p$-adic setting: the only prime is $p$, up to units, so what we use is being a $p$-adic unit. The link-reference mentioning squarefree $a$ is a discussion in number fields, with base ring $\mathbf Z$, so it's a slightly different situation. I am showing here how to *adapt* the reasoning. Just check you agree the logic is all okay.

Comment: Thanks so much, that makes sense. I was also wondering if there is anything special by $\mathbb Q_p$ or it can be (almost) any $p$-adic field $F$, with $u^{1/p}\notin F$.

Comment: @did try to extend the argument yourself to see what happens.